# Cannot connect to Jupyter Server on Visual Studio Code (Python Anaconda)

Tags: python, visual-studio, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I'm trying to do a Coursera course (link to GitHub assignment):

https://github.com/hse-aml/hadron-collider-machine-learning/tree/master/week1

When I launch the code in Visual Studio Code using Python Anaconda as the interpreter, however, I get this:

[Error 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/72tHR.png)

I know I have added Anaconda to the PATH variables and that I selected the correct interpreter in Visual Studio Code (Ctrl+Shift+P), but it just does not change the message in the top right corner. I don't even get an error unless I run the code, which can be seen in the image above.

Where do I go from here? Is there something I'm missing?

EDIT:
Here is the text format of the error:

Error: Jupyter cannot be started. Error attempting to locate jupyter: 'Kernelspec' module not installed in the selected interpreter (C:\Users\Michael\anaconda3\envs\pyml2\python.exe).
Please re-install or update 'jupyter'.
at b.startServer (c:\Users\Michael.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.5.78807\out\client\extension.js:92:270430)
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:85:5)
at async b.createServer (c:\Users\Michael.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.5.78807\out\client\extension.js:92:269873)
at async connect (c:\Users\Michael.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.5.78807\out\client\extension.js:92:397876)
at async w.ensureConnectionAndNotebookImpl (c:\Users\Michael.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.5.78807\out\client\extension.js:16:556625)
at async w.ensureConnectionAndNotebook (c:\Users\Michael.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.5.78807\out\client\extension.js:16:556303)
at async w.clearResult (c:\Users\Michael.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.5.78807\out\client\extension.js:16:552346)
at async w.reexecuteCell (c:\Users\Michael.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.5.78807\out\client\extension.js:16:540374)
at async w.reexecuteCells (c:\Users\Michael.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.5.78807\out\client\extension.js:16:537541)

In the top right corner, it has a disconnected symbol next to "Jupyter Server: " and says "Python 3.7.2 32-bit: Not Started", even though the interpreter and Anaconda is using 3.7.6.

Comment: Have you already tried the proposed things (update or re-install jupyter)?

Comment: Better post your error in the question as text instead of an image. This will help people because the image doesn't load sometimes.

Comment: I think I have tried updating/re-installing jupyter, but just in case I can try again. Where should I go to update/reinstall it? Anaconda Navigator?

Comment: Posted the error in text format. Good call.

Comment: @Michael Peters. I'm a dev on this extension. Usually this issue is with a bad jupyter install. If you want you can open up an anaconda prompt with your selected environment and try running this:

python -m jupyter kernelspec list

That should list out any kernelspecs available on your system. That looks to be the command that is failing in your example above. And if it doesn't work from the command prompt then it will fail from vscode as well.

Comment: Apologies for the late reply. Once I got it working I forgot to post an update. I think it may have been a PATH variable problem. I removed all PATH variables, uninstalled anaconda (incl. jupyter), reinstalled everything and it worked. I guess turning it off and turning it back on again still solves many issues.